# is there a good example of using NGRX with angular-fire

Tags: angular, firebase, angularfire2, ngrx-store

Using NGRX/store and firebase for the first time.

the code in the reservation service looks like this:

```
reservations: FirebaseListObservable<Reservation[]> = null;
```

with a create method like this:

```
createReservation(reservation: Reservation): FirebaseListObservable<Reservation> {
    return this.reservations.push(reservation)
  }
```

the NGRX/effect looks like this:

```
@Effect()
  create$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$
.ofType(reservationsActions.CREATE)
.map((action: reservationsActions.Create) => action.payload)
.switchMap((reservation) =>
  this.reservationsService.createReservation(reservation)
    .map( (createdReservation: Reservation) => new reservationsActions.CreateSuccess(createdReservation))
);
```

I'm getting this error

```
Type 'ThenableReference' is not assignable to type 'FirebaseListObservable<Reservation>'
```

I've tried

```
:Observable<any>
```

I get this

```
Property '_isScalar' is missing in type 'ThenableReference'.
```

all the NGRX stuff is wired correctly, it's only when I try to use it with angular-fire that I have issues since it's not your typical CRUD... GET, POST etc.

is there a good example of using NGRX and angular-fire.

```
createReservation(reservation: Reservation): Observable<any> {
return this.db.list(`${this.basePath}/${this.uid}`).push(reservation);
```

}

Comment: can you describe your problem in detail, i have created a app using ngrx v4. and just one method using firebase [the effects](https://github.com/rahulrsingh09/FootBallScores/blob/master/src/app/competition/state-management/competition.effects.ts).More on [ngrx](https://rahulrsingh09.github.io/AngularConcepts/ngrx)

Comment: I have a 'createReservation' action that triggers a createReservation effect that switchMaps into the reservationService.createReservation(reservation) method with the reservation as a payload. I guess I have to write the methods in the service a bit different when using NGRX and firebase together, because I only get these errors and im trying to use the 2 libraries together.

Comment: you might want to check that git link i gave you for the football app i build using ngrx and angular , i just use a pagecount in firebase but i guess that can be helpful

Comment: OK thank you will do.

Comment: Do you have an example where you are writing to the firebase database using push?

Comment: for push just have a payload and add that to the method that will work

Comment: I'm passing the payload in the effect and using it in the service, I believe the problem is in the service. no matter how i write it I get these errors Type 'ThenableReference' is not assignable to type 'Observable<any>'.
  Property '_isScalar' is missing in type 'ThenableReference'.

Comment: can you show the service method ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152348/discussion-between-mel-pacheco-and-rahul-singh).

Answer (score 3):

I would gladly recommend Maximilian Schwarzmüller's course on Udemy["Angular 4 (formerly Angular 2) - The Complete Guide"](https://www.udemy.com/the-complete-guide-to-angular-2/). 
This epic course covers the whole Angular ecosystem and he has (just last week) published a 'bonus course' on NgRx where he is integrating with a Firebase backend, without using angularfire2.

As is usually the case when asking Max a question, the result has been my rethinking my own assumptions; for now I am left asking why did I choose to add a dependency like angularfire2 in an already hairy stack?

Think about it - the promise of NgRx (at least as I see it) is to move a large portion (hopefully all) of your service layer and business logic out of your into the store.  In this paradigm I am not sure angularfire2 brings much to the party.

I have been having difficulties incorporating angularfire2 and NgRx v4, and like you I have not been able to find anyone who has them playing nicely.

I think that for now I will take Max's lead and avoid dependencies on angularfire2 until I have a reasonably complex bit of code working on a pure HTML basis (firebase alone)  then I can incrementally introduce angularfire2 modules and see if anything breaks.

Comment: Yea just saw the update to the course, can't wait to dig into it.

Answer (score 0):

[ThenableReference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.ThenableReference) that you were getting was the only response you were getting as a success from Firebase. It doesn't return the whole object you need, so you have to retrieve it yourself.

I will write down what worked for me, you should take this with a pinch of salt.

```
createReservation(reservation: Reservation): FirebaseListObservable<Reservation> {
    const reservations = this.afs.collection('reservations');
    const id = this.afs.createId();
    reservations.doc(id).set({ id, ...reservation});
    return reservations.doc(id);
 }
```

I have added this unique id to the reservation itself, so you can reference it for DELETE and UPDATE later. Then in the effect you should do the following:

```
@Effect()
  create$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$
.ofType(reservationsActions.CREATE)
.pipe(
    map((action: reservationsActions.Create) => action.payload),
    map((reservation) => this.reservationsService.createReservation(reservation),
    switchMap(reservationDocument: AngularFirestoreDocument) => from(reservationDocument.ref.get())),
    map(snapshot: any) => {
       const createdReservation = snapshot.data();
       return new reservationsActions.CreateSuccess(createdReservation));
  })
);
```

Beware that now in reducer you should map entities by index, because *ngFor will fail to render if you map entities by id (id is now something like **4SzQ69wsaDjGIu1n9YL7** , i.e. the same as the reference)